# How do I create an XML that display the links of several hotels?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create an XSLT stylesheet. What must I do to change the nodes based on their id number?? I want to be able to create and run an xml file with the hotelnames fonts in different colors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="main.xsl"?>
<main>


<title>Property List</title>

    <hotelslist>
        <hotels id="1">
            <hotelname>Burj Al Arab</hotelname>
            <city>Dubai</city>
            <country>UAE</country>
        </hotels>

        <hotels id="2">
            <hotelname>la tremoille</hotelname>
            <city>Paris</city>
            <country>France</country>
        </hotels>

        <hotels id="3">
            <hotelname>The waldorf astoria</hotelname>
            <city>New York</city>
            <country>USA</country>
        </hotels>

        <hotels id="4">
            <hotelname>The Monte Carlo</hotelname>
            <city>Las Vegas</city>
            <country>USA</country>
        </hotels>
    </hotelslist>



</main>
```

/////////////////
foo ann asnn asndn asdn

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. What is your expected xml result?

Answer (score 0):

This template:

```
  <xsl:template match="main/hotelslist/hotels">
    <p>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('class-', attribute::id)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select='hotelname' />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="title" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your XML, gives this result:

```
<p class="class-1">Burj Al Arab</p>

<p class="class-2">la tremoille</p>

<p class="class-3">The waldorf astoria</p>

<p class="class-4">The Monte Carlo</p>
```

Which you can then style with a CSS like this:

```
class-1 { 
    color:green;
}
```